# Pass @Html.DropDownList selection using @Html.ActionLink with ViewModel to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor, html.actionlink

I've been reading through posts for two days regarding this, and still have not figured out the answer. I want to capture the DropDownList selection within my ModelView, pass this to a @Html.ActionLink, which will send it back to a specific Action within the Controller.

My ViewModel:

```html
    public class ViewModelShipments
    {
        public ViewModelShipments()
        {
            tblShipments = new tblShipments();
        }
        public tblShipments tblShipments;
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ShipmentIDsList;
        public string SelectedShipmentID; 
    }
```

My Controller:

```html
public ActionResult SelShipment(string SelectedShipmentID)//for ShipmentID change via DropDownList
        {
            int id = db.tblShipments.Max(p => p.ShipmentID); // find last ShipmentID
            if (SelectedShipmentID != null)
            {
                id = Int32.Parse(SelectedShipmentID);//convert text to int
            }
```

My View:

```
            @Html.DropDownListFor(expression: model=>model.SelectedShipmentID,selectList: Model.ShipmentIDsList) @* render DropDownList object*@
            @Model.SelectedShipmentID @* display value of SelectedShipmentID *@

            <!-- Upon Click, send selected ID to controller --> 
            <!-- the ActionLink is working, but the routeValues: always contain NULL -->
            @Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Submit", actionName: "SelShipment", controllerName: "Shipment", routeValues: Model.SelectedShipmentID, htmlAttributes: null)
```

Why does the ActionLink(..., routeValues: Model.SelectedShipmentID,...) always return NULL to the Controller ? The Model.SelectedShipmentID is not updated with the DropDownList selected id. Please help as I'm running out of time on this.

Comment: You need javascript/jquery to change the url of the link based on the selected value, or better post the value using a form (can be a `FormMethod.Get`). And the reason its null is that Razor code is evaluated on the server before its sent to the client so the route value that's added is the initial value of `Model.SelectedShipmentID` (it does not change just because you select something in your UI

Comment: And since `ShipmentID` is typeof `int` your method parameter and model property should be `int? SelectedShipmentID` (not `string`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I'm working through the options. Have managed to retrieve the SelectedShipmentID by POST'ing the form back to the controller. With 60 fields on the form, I'll be looking @Stephen's suggestion below of using Ajax and partial views to minimize unnecessary data exchange. This was the initial intention of using the ActionLink. So much to learn... so little time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view, so the value of your route parameter will be the initial value of `SelectedShipmentID`. Selecting a value from a dropdownlist does not change the url you have already rendered.

You could use javascript/jquery to handle the dropdownlist's `.change()` event (or the links `.click()` event) to update the url, however the better way to handle this is by using a form that makes a GET to your controller method

```cs
@model ViewModelShipments
@using (Html.BeginForm("SelShipment", "Shipment", FormMethod.Get))
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedShipmentID, Model.ShipmentIDsList, "-Please select-")
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Note the last parameter of `DropDownListFor()` add a label option allowing you to post back `null` but not sure if this is appropriate for you.

Since your binding to a value which is `int` then both your model property and method parameter should be `int?` not `string`. In additiona you should change the logic in the controller so that you are not making unnecessary database calls when a valid value is passed to the method.

```cs
public ActionResult SelShipment(int? SelectedShipmentID)
{
  if (!SelectedShipmentID.HasValue)
  {
    // only necessary to call database if SelectedShipmentID is null
    SelectedShipmentID = db.tblShipments.Max(p => p.ShipmentID)
  }
  ....
}
```

Side note: From your view model properties, I assume you wanting to display some data in the view based on the value of the selected `ShipmentID`. If so you should consider using ajax to post the selected value to a controller method that returns the `tblShipments` data based on the value, either as a partial view or as json, and update the current page, rather than doing a complete page refresh each time.